# devmem2 command returning "weird" value

Tags: command-line, ram, raspberrypi, arm

I'm currently working on the raspberry pi 3, reading the manuali see that register 0x76f09000 is supposed to let me know if the GPIO pin is high or low.

I'm using the devmem2 command

```
$devmem2 0x7e200034
/dev/mem opened 
Memory mapped at address 0x76f2f000
Value at address 0x2116026420 (0x76f2f034): 0x0
```

According to the data sheet, register 0x76f2f000 is supposed to be a 32 bit register. I don't understand what the value of the address is telling me in this case since it's returning 10 digits (hexadecimals?)!! Anybody have any idea what this value is.

Link to the arm manual (page 96): https://www.raspberrypi.org/app/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 10 digit number is what the physical address is but converted into decimal form (try it out for your self http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter). 
The information I am interested in is 0x76f2f034, this is the 32 bit value. You need to convert this into binary to find out which which GPIO pin is high or low (0111 0110 1111 0010 1111 0000 0011 0100). 
However i don't think that it is a straight 1 to 1 mapping regarding the data sheet and the actual GPIO pins located on the Raspberry PI

Comment: You are correct, despite of 0x prefix the 10 digit number is decimal. See the source: https://github.com/VCTLabs/devmem2/blob/master/devmem2.c line 94. Anyway if you want PHYSICAL address 0x76f2f000, this is what must be the program's 1st arg. You have a different value there: 0x7e200034. See the difference?